# Counting special characters with PHP

Tags: php, strlen

I want to count the number of characters in a textfield on my website. The textfield accepts any type of input from a user, including ascii art and other special characters. If the user types in normal characters, I can use strlen($message) to return the value, but if the user uses special characters (such as Â or ©), the count is incorrect.

Is there are simple way to count everything without having to do any heavy lifting?

Comment: http://php.net/mb_strlen for multi-byte character strings

Comment: If you want to know how long a string will be on the screen, that's tough. `mb_strlen()` will only count "characters", but there are characters that don't display, characters that modify preceding characters (in Unicode, at least), etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your input is UTF-8 encoded and you want to count Unicode *graphemes*, you can do this:

```
$count = preg_match_all('/\X/u', $text);
```

[Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#grapheme) is some explanation. Unicode graphemes are "characters" (Unicode codepoints), including the "[combining marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)" that can follow them.

`mb_strlen($text, 'UTF-8')` would count combining marks as separate characters (and `strlen($text)` would give you the total bytecount).

Since, judging by a comment of yours, your input could have some characters converted to their HTML entity equivalent, you should first do an `html_entity_decode()`:

```
$count = preg_match_all('/\X/u', html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

---

**UPDATE**

The `intl` PECL extension now provides `grapheme_strlen()` and other [`grapheme_*()` functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.intl.grapheme.php) (but only if you have the [`intl` PECL extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) installed, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Both strlen & mb_strlen are working fine for me.

Either the special characters entered may wont show (Unicode). So try which are the characters that are not readable.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: mb_stren does work for the examples I gave. But if someone types less-than sign "<" it gets converted to &lt; by wordpress and counts as 4 characters. Since I believe that is the only character that gets converted by wordpress, I'm thinking I'd be able to count the number of less-than signs (n), and subtract 4n from the total character count.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
function countumlauts($str) {
    return strlen($str) - iconv_strlen($str);
}
```

**How it works:** Special chars use more than one byte. strlen counts the bytes, while iconv_strlen counts the chars.